# Restrict read access on certain folders

Tags: root-access, privacy

I am looking for a way to limit read access for certain folders, for privacy reasons.

E.g. I want to have a folder that will be used for sensitive data. It shall only be accessed by a file manager app, office app, and picture gallery. And nobody else shall be allowed to read it (e.g. untrusted apps that may violate my privacy).

I am rooted, with CM11. Is there any existing solution for that? Or will it be a dirty hack?

I am thinking of creating a new user group, assigning the "private" folder to this group, and adding the apps (additionally) to this group. Is this possible? Or will I mess something up when doing this? I have a rough overview how the linux user system works, but I do not really know how the android users work in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Install an app like **[KeepSafe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kii.safe)**, which is optimized for pictures, or **[Super Vault](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hideimagevideo.supervault)**, which you can store different types of files in. They encrypt your data and require a password to unlock, so those will probably be the best choices for you. They don't even require root.

If you want to go a step further, you can even install an app like **[AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock)** to require a password to open a specific app.

**Alternative method:** You can install a file manager like **[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)** and *zip* a specific folder with a password, so no one can unzip the encrypted data without the password. *Keep in mind that you will have to unzip and re-zip every time you want to add/remove/modify a file.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I feel these vaults are only for specific media data, I want to use it for spreadsheets, documents,... Can the office app access files stored in the SuperVault? zip does not work as well, since the unzipped files will be on the media storage public for all - and it is very annoying to always zip/unzip. Any other ideas? I want to block apps to misuse my data, not people that have access to my device. So I want to create a share only between specific trusted apps. regards, Arnschi

Comment: Can these apps prevent someone from accessing the folders via MTP for example?

Comment: I am not sure about the vault apps, though I have successfully used ES File Manager to encrypt entire folders and subdirectories without compressing them.

Comment: FYI, except KeepSafe, the rest have been removed from Google Play Store.